# How to handle dblClick event on Fullcalendar daySlot?

Tags: fullcalendar

I know its possible to receive a `dayClick` event on Fullcalendar. But I would like to manage just the double click event. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

currently not possible, will be possible when [dayRender](http://code.google.com/p/fullcalendar/issues/detail?id=191) is developed. Alternately, you could look at [this person's patch](http://code.google.com/p/fullcalendar/issues/detail?id=375) but can't say how far you'd get with it.

Answer (score 1):

There is a manageable way to handle double clicks in the FullCalendar `dayClick` event.

The "300" is really just an arbitrary amount of time in milliseconds to determine whether or not the clicks are close enough to call them a double click. If you want them faster or slower you can shrink or increase the number accordingly.

```javascript
var this_click_time = new Date().getTime();

var time_since_last_click = this_click_time - last_click_time;

last_click_time = this_click_time;

if(time_since_last_click < 300)
{
    // Double Click = true;
}
```

Comment: Great technique, works a treat! Just a side note, a global var has to be defined `var last_click_time = new Date().getTime();` before starting `.fullCalendar()`.